# Performance of IEnumerable<T>.Count() - difference between iterating over value types and reference types

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm trying to optimize counting elements in collection (`IEnumerable<T>`)

Since this data is loaded from In-Memory Cache there is no point switching to using `IQueryable<T>.Count()` (in order to have simple database call `SELECT count(1) FROM TableT` instead of iterating over whole list of `IEnumerable<T>`)

So I just had an idea, that maybe iterating over collection (IEnumerable) of value type (e.g. int) might be quicker than iterating over collection of reference type

`myEnumerable.Count();`

replaced with this:

`myEnumerable.Select(el => el.Id).Count();`

Don't know if it's true and not sure how to test it properly, but first simple estimations suggest that iterating over `IEnumerable<int>` is slightly quicker (like 5-10%) than iterating over `IEnumerable<some-business-object>`

So, question is - is there any difference for iterating over collection whether collection holds value types or reference types?

Comment: if tou are doing `.Select(el => el.Id)` it doesn't matter because your anyways iterating `myEnumerable`

Comment: What is type of underlying collection of `myEnumerable`? If it implements `ICollection`, count will be taken from `Count` property, otherwise collection will be enumerated

Comment: If your data is in-memory just store it in List if you need `.Count()` as `Enumearble.Count` is optimized for `ICollection` cases...

Comment: If you *actually* care about performance then your cache should expose a type that knows it's own size, i.e. `ICollection<T>`, rather than exposing an `IEnumerable<T>` and forcing the caller to iterate over the entire thing just to get the count.  Worrying about the type of the objects in the sequence/collection is not your top priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> myEnumerable.Count();
>
> replaced with this:
>
> myEnumerable.Select(el => el.Id).Count();

That definitely fall performance! I don't know how you compare these that conclude it's better but you can easily compare them as follows:

```
class TestObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dataRef = Enumerable.Empty<TestObj>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        dataRef = dataRef.Append(new TestObj { Id = i });
    }

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        dataRef.Count();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"By Ref: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0} Sec");

    sw.Restart();
    var dataVal = dataRef.Select(p => p.Id);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        dataVal.Count();
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"By Val: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0} Sec");
}
```

Results:

```
By Ref: 0.002 Sec
By Val: 4.111 Sec
```

Generally `ValueType` and `ReferenceType` if we consider them independently as two enumerable, don't have any significant different in iterating time and counting.
But what you did above is adding addition enumeration on reference type enumerable to convert it to value type enumerable and that leads to many overhead and degregation of performance.

If performance is your concern and you're ready to pay its cost by memory, you can use `.ToList()` and then `.Count()` will takes near to zero.

Comment: .ToList() is taking time not just memory, so it seems `IEnumerable<T>.ToList().Count` is not faster than `IEnumerable<T>.Count()`

Comment: @Prokurors: Ofcourse, but the main benefit here is that it's not enumeration anymore, it's real collection and could be cached locally or globaly. You pay once and use many times without cost